# php exec producing Could not open input file error, but not all the times

Tags: php, exec, background-process

I'm facing a weird issue with PHP exec() function. I had a REST api which customers will call for inserts. In that API call I have to run a php file which was obviously a background process. So I'm triggering that file through PHP exec() function with an argument. This was not working as expected. My API can get 10 to 20 calls per minute. If I get 10 calls, the background file needs to trigger 10 times. But my that background file triggers 4 to 6 times only. The remaining instances are failing. After the output capturing below is the error I'm getting in the output

```
"Could not open input file: /var/www/my-bg-file.php"
```

Below is my exec command

```
exec("/bin/php /var/www/my-bg-file.php 223");
```

223 is the argument I'm passing to my-bg-file.php

my-bg-file.php is purely a PHP script which will run based on the id I'm passing, and also this file hardly will take 1 or max 2 seconds to complete.

Why the same file executing properly some times and some times not? 
How can I fix this issue?

By the way I also tried `system(), passthru()` functions also, but they also didn't worked.

Comment: issue resolved. It was the issue with our syncing the uploaded files to our server. It was not properly uploaded to another server.